# Opening a different window if a certain value in the database if found

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite

I'm having troubles figuring out how to check if the information in my database has a certain value to change log in screens. I wanted to open a different window when the user logs in as a teacher or a student. I did assign each person a student or teacher value in database as well. The code for else student works fine by the way.

edit: if statement is where I'm suppose to put the code.

```
   if(count == 1)
    {
        ui->statusLabel->setText("Username password correct. Username: "
                                 + uname);

        //dbConnection->connClose();

        if(query.value(""))

        {

        }
        else
        {
        // hide login window
        this->hide();
        // open admin window
        StudentDialog myStudent;
        myStudent.setModal(true);
        myStudent.exec();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You'll need to check the sqlite docs to see how to do a query from C++ (http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html), then do something like "select is_teacher from people where username = <uname>" <- injecting the value of `uname` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-sqlstatements.html

It shows this example:

```
 while (query.next()) {
     QString name = query.value(0).toString();
     int salary = query.value(1).toInt();
     qDebug() << name << salary;
 }
```

And this one:

```
 QSqlDatabase::database().transaction();
 QSqlQuery query;
 query.exec("SELECT id FROM employee WHERE name = 'Torild Halvorsen'");
 if (query.next()) {
     int employeeId = query.value(0).toInt();
     query.exec("INSERT INTO project (id, name, ownerid) "
                "VALUES (201, 'Manhattan Project', "
                + QString::number(employeeId) + ')');
 }
 QSqlDatabase::database().commit();
```

Basically the query stores the results in a 2d array.  To navigate across the columns, use the value index.  To cast it, use the `QVariant::toXXX()` options, such as `toInt()` or `toString()`, etc.  To get the next row of values that comes out of the executed query, call `query.next()`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#value

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#next

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#details

So in your case, you will probably just call:

```
bool is_teacher = query.value(0).toBool();
if(is_teacher)
{
    // ...
}
// etc
```

If you are still having trouble with some of your statements going through, try:

```
qDebug() << qPrintable(query.lastError().text());
```

Hope that helps.